# Multiply to latest previous values from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a problem on multiply a value with the other latest (but not the same date) value from other table with the same key.

For ease of understanding I'll explain it below.

Suppose we have two tables `variables` and `coefficients`:

table `coefficients`

```
date            key     coeff
-----------------------------
2019-06-01      A       1
2019-06-02      B       2
2019-06-03      A       3
2019-06-05      B       4
2019-06-06      B       5
2019-06-08      A       6
```

table `variables`

```
date            key     var
---------------------------
2019-06-02      A       7
2019-06-05      B       8
2019-06-05      A       9
2019-06-06      B       10
2019-06-07      A       11
2019-06-08      B       12
2019-06-09      A       13
```

The goal is to  multiply the value on `variable` column with the nearest previous `coeff` value.

In the end we'll have result like:

```
---------------------------
date            key     val     <-- var *   coeff   
---------------------------
2019-06-02      A       7       <-- 7   *   1       
2019-06-05      B       16      <-- 8   *   2
2019-06-05      A       27      <-- 9   *   3
2019-06-06      B       40      <-- 10  *   4
2019-06-07      A       33      <-- 11  *   3
2019-06-08      B       60      <-- 12  *   5
2019-06-09      A       78      <-- 13  *   6
```

On the `variables` table, the first row (key `A`) was dated `2019-06-02` so the we multiply `variables.var` with the previous latest (not the same date) `coefficients.coeff` of `A`, which is the `2019-06-01`'s `coeff`. Same with the second row of `B`.

I don't know where to start the query since if we `join` it on each `key` seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code to get your expected output. A sub query will pick the coeff value for the respected Key considering coefficients.date less than variables.Date.

You can check the fiddle [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e7037dd071e8837c81c2cc465bbb65b) .

```
SELECT A.date,
A.[key],
A.var * ISNULL( 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 coeff
    FROM coefficients B  
    WHERE B.[key] = A.[key] 
    AND B.date < A.date 
    ORDER BY B.date DESC 
),1) val
FROM variables A
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution for this:

```
SELECT
   result.[date],
   result.[key],
   result.[var] * result.[coeff] AS val
FROM (
   SELECT
      v.[date],
      v.[key],
      v.[var],
      (SELECT
         c.coeff
      FROM
         dbo.coefficients c
      WHERE
         c.[key] = v.[key]
      AND
         c.[date] = (SELECT MAX(c1.[date])
                     FROM dbo.coefficients c1
                     WHERE c1.[key] = v.[key] AND c1.[date] < v.[date])) AS coeff
   FROM
      dbo.variables v
) result
```

You could consider to write a function for the closest date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ClosestDate(
   @key nvarchar(1),
   @date date
)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @result date

   SELECT @result = MAX(c.[date]) FROM dbo.coefficients c WHERE c.[key] = @key AND c.[date] < @date

   RETURN @result
END
```

Then you can write the query as:

```
SELECT
   v.[date],
   v.[key],
   v.[var] * c.coeff AS [val]
FROM
   dbo.variables v
   INNER JOIN dbo.coefficients c ON c.[key] = v.[key] AND c.[date] = dbo.ClosestDate(v.[key], v.[date])
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `outer apply`:

```
select v.*, (c.coeff * v.var)
from variables v outer apply
     (select top (1) c.*
      from coefficients c
      where c.date <= v.date
      order by c.date desc
     ) v;
```